# How to come back to oldder pantheon greeter on my elementaryOS Juno

Tags: release-juno, updates, greeter

i upgraded my system this morning and i found with the surprise that the pantheon-greeter oldder has been updated in the oficial Juno version for the new style for lock screen. This is awesome, but sincerelly i prefer the style for the first greeter, mainly for the full screen background, for this reason, i like to come back to the previous pantheon-greeter if this is possible.

I like say that the new style of pantheon greeter is great, but i prefer a full screen background in the lock screen, i don't know if this can be modified in the new greeter, or how can change the pantheon-greeter to Loki version.

I thanks very much for yours answers, and i'm sorry for my short english.

Answer (score 1):

same question dude, i just found this 
https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/d3mxfi/change_new_greeters_background/

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Maybe include the answer here and leave the source link. Have a nice day!